# Solutions for long App names for both App Store/Play Store and using an icon name

Tags: android, mobile-application, ios, terminology

What is the preferred method for working with long app names? When the app name is required and can not be changed when a company might have multiple apps with similar names.

Do apps mainly keep the app store name and icon name the same? What are the disadvantages of having them different, if any? Do both Android and iOS take into account when the App Store/Play Store name are different than the app icon name?

Any good examples of long app names and how they appear in the app store and the name displayed under the app name?

Thanks,

Comment: Please focus on one question only

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a huge challenge. Apple actually has a limit. For example we tried to submit an app with the name "Will Robots Take Over the World Today?" Apple said that app name was too long. We had to shorten it to "Will Robots Take Over Today?" But that, of course, is too long as a label on the home screen. We shortened that to "Robots Today?" which fits well and was accepted by Apple.

I think the key thing is to re-write the label so it:

1. Uses words from the full name
2. Makes sense when reading it without knowing the full name
3. Fits without truncation or letter squishing

Those are general principles that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and points when trying to get around the limit.